# Why do I get SIGSEGV error when use class function from pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, android-ndk, void-pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm new in C++ and runned into first trouble. I have a GameObject class in which I have to somehow store many components. Each component is a different class, so I can't just normally use vector. I decided to store a component's type and pointer to that object. The problem is, that when I get, return that component, and use a class function which uses it's member variables, I get SIGSEGV error(yeah, sounds confusing). However, if I normally use that class and that function, I don't get a SIGSEGV error.

**GameObject.h:**

```
enum ComponentType
{
    MeshComponent // currently only one type
};

struct Component
{
    ComponentType type;
    void *pointer;
};
class GameObject
{
    private:
    std::vector<Component> components;
    public:
    void addComponent(ComponentType type);
    template<typename T> T* getComponent()
    {
        for(std::vector<Component>::size_type i = 0; i != components.size(); i++)
        {
            // will need to somehow check T type later
            if(components[i].type == MeshComponent)
            {
                return (Mesh*)&components[i].pointer;
            }
        }
        Debug::Loge(GAMEOBJECT_TAG, "No %s component in %s gameobject!", componentTypeToString(MeshComponent).c_str(), name.c_str());
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**GameObject.cpp:**

```
void GameObject::addComponent(ComponentType type)
{
    Component component;
    component.type = type;
    if(type == MeshComponent)
    {
        Mesh *mesh = new Mesh();
        component.pointer = &mesh;
    }
    components.push_back(component);
}
```

**Mesh.h**

```
class Mesh
{
    public:
    Mesh *setMeshData(std::vector<GLfloat> data);
};
```

**Mesh.cpp**

```
Mesh *Mesh::setMeshData(vector<GLfloat> data)
{
    meshData = data;
    return this;
}
```

And finally this is how I use it:

```
GameObject object;
void somefunction()
{
    object.addComponent(MeshComponent);
    object.getComponent<Mesh>()->setMeshData(triangle_data); // SIGSEGV HERE!!
    // if I use this one instead above - no sigsegv, everything is fine.
    Mesh mesh;
    mesh.setMeshData(triangle_data);
}
```

Comment: `return (Mesh*)&components[i].pointer;` Quick skim - looks like you are getting the pointer you want (`.pointer`) then taking the address of *the pointer* and returning that.

Comment: You should at the very least check that ``object.getComponent<Mesh>()`` does not return ``0``.

Comment: A std::vector<std::unique<Component>> might make life easier if you've got C++11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In here

```
    Mesh *mesh = new Mesh();
    component.pointer = &mesh;
```

you are taking the address of the pointer to `mesh`. Instead try

```
    Mesh *mesh = new Mesh();
    component.pointer = mesh;
```

because you defined your `Component`-pointer as `void* pointer`. If you wanted to take the address of `Mesh*` you would have to use `void** pointer`, but this is silly and would lead yet to another `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: Also `return (Mesh*)&components[i].pointer` which is the same kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(components[i].type == MeshComponent)
{
     return (Mesh*)&components[i].pointer;
}
```

Your return type is Mesh* but `&components[i].pointer` will be void**. 
+ the above explanation by @bas.d